# Product type of static library target in Xcodegen?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcodegen

I've created a file called `project.yml`, to generate my Swift `.xcodeproj` with `Xcodegen`. For example:

```
name: MyProject
targets:
  MyAppTarget:
    type: application
    sources:
      - MyAppTarget
    ...
  MyLibrary
    type: static library // identify the project type of the target here
    sources:
      - MyLibrary
    ...
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using `library.static` for identifing a target of static lib.
By the way, You can find anything at [XcodeGen-ProjectSpec](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen/blob/master/Docs/ProjectSpec.md#product-type)